# Node.js, React socket.io emit() not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I want to build a ReactJS/NodeJs app with Socket IO.
I am able to establish a socket connection between the client and the server, but whenever I press the button to emit a message, nothing happens on the server side, meaning the `console.log('new message:', msg)`is not triggered.

Client code:

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

function App() {

  socket.on('message', msg => {
    console.log('new message:', msg);
   });

  const handleMessageSend = () => {
    socket.emit('message', 'test');
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleMessageSend}>Send</button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Server:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', msg => {
        console.log('new message:', msg);
        socket.emit('message', msg)
    })
})

http.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 4000');
})
```

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I don't know ReactJS syntax, but in the actual HTML, it should be `onclick="handleMessageSend()"`.  Perhaps you should check the actual HTML of your page with View Page Source and see exactly what HTML was generated.  You can also insert a `console.log("calling socket.emit()")` into your `handleMessageSend()` function so you can see if it's ever getting called. I suspect the problem is not with `socket.emit()`, but with getting `handleMessageSend()` properly hooked up to the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved socket code inside `handleMessageSend`.

And you can add preventDefault to prevent your page refreshing (I am not sure if you need this because you are not using a form and submit button, but you can use it for now.)

Can you please try this and let me know if it works?

React component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
  let serverUrl = 'localhost:4000'
  let socket = io(serverUrl);
  const handleMessageSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("message", "test message")
    socket.on("message", function(msg){
      console.log("socket working on the frontend: ", msg);
    });
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleMessageSend}>Send</button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here server file :

```
const express = require ("express");
const socket = require ("socket.io");
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 4000');
})

const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', msg => {
        console.log('socket working at the backend', msg);
        io.sockets.emit('message', msg)
    })
})
```